# How do I fix the menu items background color in MediterraneanNight theme?

Tags: themes

I'm using the [MediterraneanNight theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1017469/) and the menu items in some context menus have the wrong background color. For example, when I'm in Eclipse, I select "Project" and the menu items are light gray and their background color is also light gray.
How do I fix this?

Comment: I would suggest adding screenshots to your question via the edit feature (or just add them in a comment and someone will later add it to your question). It's easier to grasp for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue, but I couldn't find any real solution (how could there be any, if simply the theme doesn't support Eclipse, and Eclipse doesn't support the theme), so I simply searched for a dark theme for Eclipse, and found one looking good named Dark Juno.

You can find the theme, and installation instructions on GitHub:

https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes

The readme includes rough instructions for setting a dark editor colour scheme as well. I hope it helps, the result satisfied me.